# have trouble with using capybara-webkit attach_file upload an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, capybara-webkit

I want to test the function to add an image to the application. How can I do this. attach_file method is not work. I don't know why.

html:

```
<form id="edit_user_5577b0c4a851ac600c000002" class="form-horizontal user-settings" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/tardis54" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div id="upload-avatar" class="control-group">
        ::before
        <label class="control-label" for="user_avatar">
            Setting avatar
        </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="form-fileupload">
                <div class="image-preview">
                    <img class="gravatar img-circle" width="60" height="60" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/7046a07b25397e4a0c838a47c88d8742?default=identicon&secure=false&size=60" data-retina-url="http://gravatar.com/avatar/7046a07b25397e4a0c838a47c88d8742?default=identicon&secure=false&size=120" alt="tardis54"></img>
                </div>
                <span class="btn btn-fileinput btn-default">
                    <span>
                        Choose file ...
                    </span>
                    <input id="user_avatar" class="input-file" type="file" name="user[avatar]"></input>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
    <div class="form-actions pull-right">
        <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update" name="commit"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

test code:

```
scenario "upload a custom avatar" do
    attach_file("user[avatar]", Rails.root + "temp4.png")
end
```

error log:

```
Failure/Error: attach_file("user[avatar]", Rails.root + "temp4.png")
 Capybara::Webkit::ClickFailed:
   Failed to click element /html/body/div[@id='content']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form[@id='edit_user_5580e19da851ac6a51000002']/div[@id='upload-avatar']/div/div/span/input[@id='user_avatar'] 
because of overlapping element /html/body/div[@id='content']/div/div/div/div/div at position 740, 627;
```

Comment: is the input field within a dropdown or standalone in a form, what does the surrounding html look like? could be a case of being more specific but need to see more html

Comment: I have added more html. Do you konw how to reslove this problem now? @Richlewis

Comment: could you trying using the `id` as a locator instead and let me know what happens

Comment: I use `attach_file("user_avatar", Rails.root + "temp4.png")` . Get same error as before.

Comment: is it not `attach_file("#user_avatar", Rails.root + "temp4.png")`

Comment: oh, I'm sorry. When I use `attach_file("#user_avatar", Rails.root + "temp4.png")`. I get error:    `Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find file field "#user_avatar"`

Comment: maybe you need to interpolate your file path so `"#{Rails.root}/path/to/image"`

Comment: It doesn't work. The image path is right. @Richlewis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using CSS to overlay another element on top of the HTML input. Some people do this because it's difficult to style HTML file inputs directly. However, doing so breaks capybara-webkit, because it needs to click on the actual HTML input field and the styled element is positioned on top of it.

This is being discussed in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/629).

You can work around it in the test by using `execute_script` to hide the overlay element, and then attempting to upload the file.

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to solve this problem.

`script = "$('#user_avatar').css({opacity: 100, display: 'block', position: 'relative', left: ''});"
page.execute_script(script)`

Answer (score 0):

I could assume that input[type=file] is not visible, thus you need initially make it visible f.e. execute javascript $("input[type=file]").show() and than attach file

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation of @tardis answer (which itself is an implementation of @joe-ferris' suggestion). I put it as an answer to be able to use code formatting.

```
# spec/support/file_uploads.rb
module FileUploads
  # Enables file uploads by capybara-webkit on pages that 
  # style file their input fields
  def attach_file_styled_input(element_id, file)
    page.execute_script("$('##{element_id}')" +
      ".css({opacity: 100, display: 'block', position: 'relative', left: ''});")
    attach_file element_id, file
  end
end
```

Don't forget to include this support module in `spec/rails_helper.rb`:

```
config.include FileUploads
```

Then use it in your feature spec like this (not spectacular):

```
attach_file_styled_input 'my_input_id', 'my_file'
```